# react storybook addon knobs not showing

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I cant seem to be getting the @storybook addon knobs working? It doesnt seem to be decorating the actual story. Pretty much followed [this](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs)

My code below.. Im using getstorybook with create-react-app

Using below packages:

```
@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.1.2,
@storybook/addon-info": "^3.1.4,
@storybook/addon-knobs": "^3.1.2,
@storybook/react": "^3.1.3
```

my setup

```
//.storybook/addons.js
import '@storybook/addon-knobs/register'

//.config
import { configure, setAddon, addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import infoAddon from '@storybook/addon-info';

setAddon(infoAddon);

function loadStories() {
  require('../stories');
}

configure(loadStories, module);

//stories/index.js
import React from 'react';
import { withKnobs, text, boolean, number } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';

const stories = storiesOf('Storybook Knobs', module);

  // Add the `withKnobs` decorator to add knobs support to your stories.
  // You can also configure `withKnobs` as a global decorator.
  stories.addDecorator(withKnobs);

  // Knobs for React props
  stories.add('with a button', () => (
    <button disabled={boolean('Disabled', false)} >
      {text('Label', 'Hello Button')}
    </button>
  ))
```

This should be a no brainer, but no suck luck.

Comment: "Show Addons" in ellipsis menu near title

Answer (score 53):

Hope this helps someone, but for some reason my addons panel suddenly disappeared from view and I couldn't figure out how to get it back. I could  see the addons markup being rendered in the "elements" pane in my dev tools - so I knew things were working. Somehow storybook stored a bad value in my `localStorage['storybook-layout']` so that the addons were positioned waaaaayyy off screen. Running the following fixed it.

```
localStorage.removeItem('storybook-layout')
```

Comment: Thanks, that saved me hours of crying! It happened to me when I updated Storybook and the knobs addon from a very old version to the latest.

Comment: this worked for me `delete localStorage['@storybook/ui/store']`

Comment: I was able to fix this simply by hitting the `D` key, which changes the addon panel orientation. (You can also do this by clicking the `...` menu button in Storybook's sidebar, and then clicking the 'Change addon orientation' option.)

Comment: You are all beautiful geniuses!

Answer (score 14):

You probably need to create the addons.js file on the storybook config folder. (By default .storybook).

Check the [Docs for knobs](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs) you need to add the following:

```
import '@storybook/addon-knobs/register';
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  I linked the notes and missing the addon register is a common error people made that made the knobs not be shown. Additionally I said probably need

Comment: This questions is for knobs not notes just FYI

Comment: You didn't even open the link or read the text right? I said the needed to create the file and on addon-notes that is a component as addon-knobb it says that. "Then create a file called addons.js in your storybook config."

Answer (score 7):

- Hitting `D` on your keyboard toggles the layout // Ray Brown

or

- You should also be able to expand the sidebar by clicking and dragging on the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try removing all the query string on the url

eg. `http://localhost:6006/?knob-is_block=false&knob-Disabled=false&knob-disabled=false&knob-Style%20lite=false&knob-show=true&knob-Size=md&knob-readOnly=false&knob-Style=default&knob-icon%20name=vertical&knob-Label=Hello%20Button&knob-Active=false&knob-is_loading=false&selectedKind=Button&selectedStory=default%20style&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs`

to `http://localhost:6006`

This worked for me.

Comment: This was my problem, thanks. This will happen the first time you install the addon and you already have a storybook page up in the browser. Need to directly go to `http://localhost:9001` or whatever port you have configured

Comment: None of the solutions posted above helped me, but for me at least the knobs panel is displayed in incognito mode

Comment: I had to delete my site data for localhost in Chrome. Otherwise it was only working in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

In Storybook 6.5 I was facing the same issue after manually adding the addon:

```
npm i @storybook/addon-knobs --dev
```

All I needed to do is to go to the **main.js** file inside the **.storybook** folder and add the following:

```
"addons": ["@storybook/addon-knobs"]
```

Then I stopped the already running storybook in the terminal using `ctrl/cmd + c` and then re-run the storybook:

```
npm run storybook
```

Hope it helps. Thank you.